# VBA Open method only working after crashing

Tags: excel, vba

My code does basically the following:

- Copy a range
- Create a new Workbook
- Paste the range in the new Workbook
- Open another (existing) workbook

  Set YestWb = Workbooks.Open(arq_path & yest_name & ".xlsx")
- etc.

When it tries to open the other workbook, sometimes it raises the following error:

Run-time Error '1004' - Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed.

However, when i simply click 'Debug' and 'Run' again, from where it had paused, it works fine. Any idea why it only works after crashing and why this error only occurs sometimes?

I've searched similar topics about this error, but I couldn't find any similar situation. Any help will be appreciated!

(Edit) here's the code:

```
Sub excel_ger(Optional auto As Boolean)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set capa = Sheets("P&L_R")
Set fff = Application.WorksheetFunction
capa.Activate

'inputs
ult_est = "NDF_USD" 
colini = "B" 
colfim = "M" 
nome_ger_mae = "GerencialV34.xlsm"

'find last row
lRow = capa.Cells(capa.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'define range to be copied
For i = 1 To lRow
    If capa.Range("G" & i).Value = "Dia" Then
        linini = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
For i = linini + 1 To lRow
    If capa.Range("B" & i).Value = ult_est Then
        linfim = i
    End If
Next i

'copy range
capa.Range(Cells(linini, colini), Cells(linfim, colfim)).Copy

'create new workbook
arq_path = "\\viseu\Gestao Tesouraria\Operadores\Lucca Cerf\3. Gerencial\Gerencial PropTrading\"
arq_name = "Gerencial PropTrading - " _
            & Year(Sheets("Painel").Range("dtref").Value) _
            & Format(Month(Sheets("Painel").Range("dtref").Value), "00") _
            & Format(Day(Sheets("Painel").Range("dtref").Value), "00")
            'nome da planilha D0 a ser criada
yest_name = "Gerencial PropTrading - " _
            & Year(Sheets("Painel").Range("dtrefd_1").Value) _
            & Format(Month(Sheets("Painel").Range("dtrefd_1").Value), "00") _
            & Format(Day(Sheets("Painel").Range("dtrefd_1").Value), "00")
            'nome da planilha de D-1 para procurar o StD depois
Set NewWb = Workbooks.Add

'Paste into the new workbook
NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlFormats

'hide columns
NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("G:H").Hidden = True
NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("J:K").Hidden = True

'no gridlines
NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

'zoom - 70%
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70

'column width
With NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("C:F")
 .ColumnWidth = .ColumnWidth * 1
End With
NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").ColumnWidth = NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").ColumnWidth * 2
'NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("I").ColumnWidth = NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("I").ColumnWidth * 1
'NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("L").ColumnWidth = NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("L").ColumnWidth * 1
NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("N").ColumnWidth = NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("L").ColumnWidth
NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("O").ColumnWidth = NewWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("L").ColumnWidth


'IT WORKS FINE UNTIL THIS LINE
'open last saved file
Set YestWb = Workbooks.Open(arq_path & yest_name & ".xlsx") 'sometimes raises error.
```

I've checked that the file does exist in the folder. The code runs after I click 'Debug' and press F5 again from where it had paused.

Comment: What are the values of `arq_path` and `yest_name` and where do you get them from?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual code. I assume you have checked that the file you are attempting to open exists?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Yes, I've checked that the file does exist  in this path.

Comment: @BigBen `arq_path = "\\viseu\Gestao Tesouraria\Operadores\Lucca Cerf\3. Gerencial\Gerencial PropTrading\"` and `yest_name = "Gerencial PropTrading - 20190712"`